# Bigquery: data export/import to/from cloud storage fails

Tags: google-bigquery

Job Log for 
Extract 12:02pm
publicdata:samples.shakespearetogs://OfficeTest/Shakes.csv
Errors:
Backend error. Job aborted.
Job ID: job_8373291c210f4d04aab9ee04efa3559b
Start Time: 12:02pm, 22 Aug 2012
End Time: 12:03pm, 22 Aug 2012
Source Table: publicdata:samples.shakespeare
Source URI: gs://OfficeTest/Shakes.csv

---

Job Log for import from GS
Errors:
Unable to read source URI: gs://OfficeTest/FLAT_CMPL.txt
Job ID: job_900a741b2eab4f95924a293110fa562f
Start Time: 9:59am, 22 Aug 2012
End Time: 9:59am, 22 Aug 2012
Destination Table: 726753267556:Test2.test
Source URI: gs://OfficeTest/FLAT_CMPL.txt

I was able to upload a simple csv file and it worked. Am I missing any setting??

Answer (score 1):

OfficeTest is not a valid bucket name -- according to [this](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming) page, bucket names must be all lower-case. Try again with gs://officetest/...

I'll fix the BigQuery validation code so that we flag this an error earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jordan. gsutil gave a response error with 400 as the status code. I created fresh bucket and uploaded the file. Now BQ recognizes it, of course its my issue now to fix the file with those double quotes.